# Join tables with null values in FK

Tags: mysql, join

I want to select some values from three tables, those tables are related by foreign keys.

The table which contains the foreign key, could have a null value in that FK.

When I select from the three tables, I don't get the rows where the FK is null.

for exemple these are my tables :

**TABLE 1 (boninterne):**

```
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|   num   |   date    | codePers | codeDept |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|1        |12/10/2012 +  NULL    |  2       |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|2        |12/10/2012 |  NULL    |  NULL    |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|3        |12/10/2012 |  1       |  2       |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|4        |12/10/2012 |  4       |  NULL    |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|5        |12/10/2012 |  12      |  2       |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|6        |12/10/2012 |  3       |  NULL    |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|7        |12/10/2012 |  1       |  2       |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|8        |12/10/2012 |  NULL    |  3       |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

**TABLE 2 (personnel):**

```
+---------+-----------+----------+
|codePers |prenomPers | nomPers  |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|1        |AA         +  ZZ      |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|4        |BB         |  WW      |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|3        |CC         |  XX      |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|12       |DD         |  VV      |
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

**TABLE 3 (departement):**

```
+---------+-----------+
|codeDept |libDept    |
+---------+-----------+
|2        |DEPT A1    +
+---------+-----------+
|3        |DEPT B1    |
+---------+-----------+
```

**and this is the query I made :**

```
SELECT num, date, CONCAT(prenomPers,' ',nomPers) AS nom, libDept 
FROM boninterne, personnel, departement
WHERE boninterne.codePers = personnel.codePers
AND boninterne.codeDept = departement.codeDept
```

**The table I want to get is :**

```
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|   num   |   date    | nom      | libDept  |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|1        |12/10/2012 +  NULL    |  DEPT A1 |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|2        |12/10/2012 |  NULL    |  NULL    |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|3        |12/10/2012 |  AA ZZ   |  DEPT A1 |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|4        |12/10/2012 |  BB WW   |  NULL    |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|5        |12/10/2012 |  DD VV   |  DEPT A1 |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|6        |12/10/2012 |  CC XX   |  NULL    |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|7        |12/10/2012 |  AA ZZ   |  DEPT A1 |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|8        |12/10/2012 |  NULL    |  DEPT B1 |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

**But what I really get is :**

```
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|   num   |   date    | nom      | libDept  |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|3        |12/10/2012 |  AA ZZ   |  DEPT A1 |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|5        |12/10/2012 |  DD VV   |  DEPT A1 |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|7        |12/10/2012 |  AA ZZ   |  DEPT A1 |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

What I have to change in my query to get that table ??

Comment: Please use ANSI 1992 joins. It will be clearer to you after that.

Comment: @Sebas What do you mean by ANSI 1992 joins ?

Comment: see http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/shadow/sql/sql1992.txt, look for 'query expressions' page 179 (onward)

Comment: He means the explicit `JOIN ... ON` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your results are correct because you are using inner joins.  You can fix this by using proper join syntax and using `left outer join` instead:

```
SELECT num, date, CONCAT(prenomPers,' ',nomPers) AS nom, libDept 
FROM boninterne
left outer join personnel
    on boninterne.codePers = personnel.codePers
left outer join departement
     on boninterne.codeDept = departement.codeDept;
```

This will keep everything in the first table, even when there is no match.